# GCP Firewall - Deny by User Agent

Tags: firewall, load-balancing, google-cloud-platform

Is it possible to block user agents in the Google Cloud Platform Firewall?  I have a specific one I require to block.  However as I offload SSL to the Load Balancer it is that which makes the request to the server and not the original user.  Therefore I cannot block at IIS level.  If so can someone let me know how.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using Global HTTP(S) Load Balancing (LB) with SSL offloading onto it, it is not possible to restrict traffic from a particular user by using GCP firewall rules as they are applied at the data center level, not the edge of the Googleś network where the LB is working. However, you can leverage Google Cloud Armor to block traffic from a particular user based on it's IP address.

By creating Cloud Armor Security Policies, you can enable IP blacklist/whitelist for HTTP(S) Load Balancing. What you need to do is to create a Cloud Armor Security Policy, add blacklist and whitelist rules to the policy, attach the Cloud Armor Security Policy to a backend service of the HTTP(S) load balancer for which you want to control access.

More information about Cloud Armor security policies can be found in this [help center article](https://cloud.google.com/armor/docs/configure-security-policies).

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example CLI command to create a rule that blocks the specified user agent. This example is for Windows.

You will need the [Compute Security Admin](https://cloud.google.com/armor/docs/configure-security-policies#iam-perms) role to execute this command.

```
set USER_AGENT=User-Agent-To-Block
set GCP_PROJECT=Your-Project-ID
set POLICY_NAME=Your-Cloud-Armor-Policy-Name
set RULE_PRIORITY=1000

gcloud compute security-policies rules create %RULE_PRIORITY% ^
--project %GCP_PROJECT% ^
--security-policy %POLICY_NAME% ^
--description "Block this user-agent" ^
--expression "has(request.headers['user-agent']) && request.headers['user-agent'].contains('%USER_AGENT%')" ^
--action "deny-403"
```

The above command adds (creates) a rule for an existing security policy. The security policy must be assigned to an HTTP(S) Load Balancer backend.